# A regular expression about folder name

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to test that a string meets the following rules:

1. It must not begin with `.`.
2. It must not end with `.`.
3. It must not include special characters like `!@#$%^&*`, but can include `.`.
4. It must not include two dots `.` side by side.

Sample valid input:

- `na.me` (single dot in middle)

Sample invalid input:

- `.name`  (begins with dot)
- `name.`  (ends with dot)
- `na..me` (includes two dots side-by-side)
- `$name`  (special character not allowed in any position)
- `name#`  (likewise)
- `na#me`  (likewise)

Comment: Why use a regex? Why not just test that the string satisfies each of these properties? You will end up doing exactly that in order to provide meaningful feedback to the user ("Names may not begin with a period (.)").

Comment: Because I want to use a Regex Validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
^(\w+\.?)*\w+$
```

If not in ECMAScript, then replace the `\w`'s with `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

The approach here is that instead of citing what's NOT acceptable, it's easier to cite what's acceptable.
Translation of the expression is:

- Start with one or many letters, followed by zero or one period (.)

  - All of which can occur zero or many times
- End with at least one letter

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your translation enlightened me. Thanks again.

Comment: what about other valid characters like spaces or '-' or '(' or ')' ? The regex does not take those characters into account.

Comment: @Dorian `/^([\w|\(|\)\[|\]\-|\.]+\.?)*[\w|\(|\)\[|\]\-|\.]+$/g` Something like that maybe? It's kind of a dirty workaround

Comment: This is missing valid characters like @Dorian mentions, like single quote.